# How do you test a jQuery UI Dialog using WatiN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, watin

I can't seem to get a hold of it!

First attempt failed:

```
string url = "http://jquery_ui_dialog.aspx";
IE jQueryDialog = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(url));
```

Second attempt failed:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    if (p.MainWindowTitle == url + " - Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
        // this doesn't find it.
    }
}
```

3rd tries the charm?

Answer (score 4):

A jquery UI dialog is just a html element that is powered by JQuery UI to make it look like a window, but it is NOT a window. you cannot attach to it, but you can simply retrieve it from the DOM.

If you dialog was initialized like this:

```
$('div#dialog_id').dialog();
```

you can simply access to it by doing:

```
Div dialog = Browser.Div("dialog_id");
```